# Iterator running out of Bounds

Tags: java, list, nullpointerexception, iterator

I need to implement my own Iterator for my List class that functions like a Stack and implements java.lang.Iterable. 
The Iterator method that is implemented in the List class should return an Iterator.

```
 @Override
public Iterator<E> iterator() {

    return new Iterator<>() {

        private MyEntry<E> it = begin;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {

            if(pos.next != null) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
            }

        @Override
        public E next() {
            if (!hasNext()) {
                reset();
            }
            else {
                it = it.next;
            }
            return it.o;
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {

        }
    };
}
```

The List itself works like a Stack. It has an begin Entry that marks the beginning of the List. Each Entry holds a reference to the next Entry. With the pos Element the List keeps track of its position. The advance() method allows you to pass through the list Entry by Entry. The elem() method returns the Value that the Entry holds at the position pos. The add() method adds an Entry at the end of the List. The delete() method removes the Entry at pos.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class MyList<E> implements Cloneable, java.lang.Iterable {


public MyList() {
    pos = begin = new MyEntry<E>();
}

public boolean empty() {
    return begin.next == null;
}

public boolean endpos() { // true, if end has been reached
    return pos.next == null;
}

public void reset() {
    pos = begin;
}

public void advance() {
    if (endpos()) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Already at the end of this List");
    }
    pos = pos.next;
}

public E elem() {
    if (endpos()) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Already at the end of this List");
    }
    return pos.next.o;
}


public void add(E x) {
    MyEntry<E> newone = new MyEntry<E>(x, pos.next);

    pos.next = newone;
}


public void delete() {
    if (endpos()) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Already at the end of this List");
    }
    pos.next = pos.next.next;
}
```

The Entrys that the List holds have a Generic Value o and a reference next tho the next MyEntry

```
    class MyEntry<E>  {

    MyEntry<E> next;
    E o;

    MyEntry() {
        this(null, null);
    }

    MyEntry(E o) {
        this(o, null);
    }

    MyEntry(E o, MyEntry<E> e) {
        this.o = o;
        this.next = e;
    }
}
```

But at the moment when I am testing it with my test class MyListTest I get the three test Strings out, but after that the Programm throws an NullPointerException in the next() method at return it.o

```
import org.junit.Test;
import java.util.*;

public class MyListTest {

 @Test
 public void test() {
     MyList list = new MyList();
     Iterator itr = list.iterator();

    list.add("a");
    list.add("b");
    list.add("c");

    while(itr.hasNext()) {
        Object element = itr.next();
        System.out.println(element + " ");
    }

    iter.remove();

    while(itr.hasNext()) {
        Object element = itr.next();
        System.out.println(element + " ");
    }
}
```

}

---

My Question is why the Iterator runs out of bounds after the last Entry and how I can prevent that.

Comment: How do you determine what `pos.next` is?

Comment: The Entrys that the List holds have an Reference to the next Entry

Comment: So show us the code for `MyList`

Comment: What is `pos` and how is it relevant to your iterator?

Comment: Why does `hasNext()` reference `pos`, and `next()` reference `it`?

Comment: Ah I see. I used the wrong reference there. In the next() method it should have been pos instead of it. Also the private MyEntry<E> it isnt needed at all. Test also runs without exit and only returns the three test Strings and doesnt run out of bounds anymore.

Comment: Actually, `private MyEntry<E> it` **is** needed, and **both** `hasNext()` and `next()` should use it (`it`, that is), and **neither** should have anything to do with `pos`!  The whole idea of an `Iterator` is that it **keeps its own position**, independent of whatever is going on in the `List` itself.

Comment: So i that case it would be wise to change the hasNext() so it checks if it.next != null

Comment: Yes.  If you've decided that `it` will always point to the `MyEntry` whose `next` points to the next item to return , then the result of `hasNext()` will be based on whether or not `it.next` is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

So the Solution was that the hasNext() method

```
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {

            if(pos.next != null) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Should have been

```
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {

            if(it.next != null) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Because neither hasNext() nor next() should interfere with the pos element. 
The Iterator should keep its own position independent from the rest of the class.